# Dynamics CRM - advanced find row count is different when exported to excel

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In Microsoft Dynamics 2011:
I did a very basic advanced find and the number of records returned was 13,449. I exported this to excel and the number of rows in the spreadsheet was 13,486. For the life of me I can't see any reason why it should be exporting 37 more records than were in the advanced find results.

I tried exporting the raw fetch to try running it in isolation, but there is a 5000 row limit so I couldn't. Dynamics seems to page through the records once it hits 5000.
Has anyone else had this issue or be able to help please?

Answer (score 1):

1. Most likely the data changes during the time you are exporting and 37 more records match the query criteria. Refresh the result in Advanced Find and check the number.
2. If possible, run the query in SQL and check the result.
3. If the view contains any multiple line text field, I suggest you check if any of these values take more than one rows in Excel. Normally CRM export feature puts all the text in one line, but you may check that just in case.
4. If Advanced Find is your only tool and you really need to find the issue, do a research on the exported data, find the column that has the most distributed values. E.g. a currency field "CurrentValue" that contains 1000 distinct values out of your 13000+ records. Use the distinct values to retrieve sub data set so you can easily compare the result from Advanced Find and the Excel sheet, e.g. add a condition that "CurrentValue" is between 0 and 100. Once you find the 37 records that not shown in your Advanced Find, you can then look into the record data and find out the cause.

Comment: 1. I was testing out of hours when no one was using the system so this cannot be the case.

Comment: 2. I replicated the exported fetch in sql and although not being exact was within 2 rows of being the same as the count in the list. This would indicate that the export is the incorrect party.

Comment: 3. All the rows were fully populated so this is not the case.

Comment: 4. Cannot find a column with more than 200 distinct values. So still stuck.

Comment: @Nick so you are able to run the query in SQL. This makes it much easier. You can either (a) import the exported data into a SQL table, and compare with the dataset you get from the SQL query, get the records exist in the new table but not in your dataset (b) run the SQL query and export the result into a EXCEL sheet, first make sure the total record amount is same with that in SQL, then compare the result with the EXCEL data exported from CRM to find the 37 records

Comment: @Nick I strongly recommend you import the exported data into a SQL table. There you can do lots of things easily and efficiently.